Disable Loudness in CM102-A+/102S+ audio controller
In windows to disable "loudness I only have to go to "Custom" tab and uncheck the "Loudness" box.
Windows Loudness control:

When I reboot in Ubuntu by sound alone I can tell that "Loudness" is,
but there no option to disable it in pulseaudio.
Advanced settings tab:

Configuration tab:

The adapter appears in lsusb as:
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0103 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM102-A+/102S+ Audio Controller

card list in pactl list as:
Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.usb-C-Media_INC._USB_Sound_Device-00
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 8
    Properties:
            alsa.card = "2"
            alsa.card_name = "Audio Advantage MicroII"
            alsa.long_card_name = "C-Media INC. Audio Advantage MicroII at usb-0000:00:14.0-3, full speed"
            alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
            device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.0"
            sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/sound/card2"
            udev.id = "usb-C-Media_INC._USB_Sound_Device-00"
            device.bus = "usb"
            device.vendor.id = "0d8c"
            device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics, Inc."
            device.product.id = "0103"
            device.product.name = "CM102-A+/102S+ Audio Controller"
            device.serial = "C-Media_INC._USB_Sound_Device"
            device.string = "2"
            device.description = "CM102-A+/102S+ Audio Controller"
            module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
            device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Profiles:
            output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
            output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
            off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo
    Ports:
            analog-output: Analog Output (type: Analog, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
                    Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo
            iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
                    Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo

How do I disable this Loudness feature in Ubuntu?
